# Jquery submit() function not executing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, codemirror

I am trying to intercept the form submission in HTML, add a value to it, and then continue it's normal submission. I am new to jquery and web development in general. I found you could use the jquery submit function but it's not even executing. The goal is to capture the user's input to the CodeMirror plugin and submit that as part of the form.

Script

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-o88AwQnZB+VDvE9tvIXrMQaPlFFSUTR+nldQm1LuPXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    var instructionsCodeMirror = null
    function configureCodeMirror() {
        const codemirror_config = {
            value: "${assignment.instructions}",
            lineNumbers: true,
            mode: "text/x-markdown",
            lineWrapping: true,
            indentWithTabs: true,
            lineWiseCopyCut: true,
            autoCloseBrackets: true,
        }
        const instructionsTextArea = document.getElementById("instructions");
        instructionsCodeMirror = CodeMirror(function (elt) {
            instructionsTextArea.parentNode.replaceChild(elt, instructionsTextArea);
        }, codemirror_config);
        instructionsCodeMirror.setSize('100%');

    }
    window.addEventListener("load", configureCodeMirror, false)
    $("#edit-assignment").submit( function(eventObj) {
        eventObj.preventDefault()
        console.log('intercept')
        $("<input />").attr("instructions", "hidden")
            .attr("name", "something")
            .attr("type", "hidden")
            .val(instructionsCodeMirror.getValue())
            .appendTo(this);
        this.submit()
    });
</script>
```

HTML

```
            <form role="form" id="edit-assignment" action="/assignments/${assignment.id}" method="post">
            <div class="row gx-4 mb-2">
                <div class="col-auto my-auto">
                    <div class="h-100">
                        <input id="title" name="title" class="mb-1" value="${assignment.title}"
                               style="font-weight: bold;font-size: large">
                        <div class="form-group pt-2"
                             style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: left; align-items: center">
                            <label for="total-attempts" style="margin-right: 8px">Total Attempts: </label>
                            <input id="total-attempts" name="total-attempts" class="mb-0 font-weight-normal text-sm"
                                   type="number" value="${assignment.attempts}">
                        </div>
                        <p class="mb-0 font-weight-normal text-xs pt-2">
                            ${assignment.referenceId}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">

                <div class="row pt-3">
                    <label for="instructions"
                           style="font-variant: small-caps;font-weight: bolder">Instructions.</label>
                    <div class="input-group input-group-outline mb-3">
                    <textarea id="instructions"
                              form="edit-assignment"
                              rows="5">
                    </textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row pt-3 w-100">
                    <label for="success-message" style="font-variant: small-caps;font-weight: bolder">Success
                        Message.</label>
                    <div class="input-group input-group-outline mb-3">
                    <textarea id="success-message"
                              name="success-message"
                              class="w-100 form-control"
                              form="edit-assignment"
                              style="resize: none">${assignment.successMessage}</textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row pt-3 w-100">
                    <label for="failure-message" style="font-variant: small-caps;font-weight: bolder">Failure
                        Message.</label>
                    <div class="input-group input-group-outline mb-3">
                    <textarea id="failure-message"
                              name="failure-message"
                              class="w-100 form-control"
                              form="edit-assignment"
                              style="resize: none">${assignment.failureMessage}</textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row pt-3 w-100">
                    <label for="expected-output" style="font-variant: small-caps;font-weight: bolder">Expected
                        Output.</label>
                    <div class="input-group input-group-outline mb-3">
                    <textarea id="expected-output"
                              name="expected-output"
                              class="w-100 form-control"
                              form="edit-assignment"
                              style="resize: none">${assignment.expectedOutput}</textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm input-group input-group-outline mb-3">
                    <input
                            type="submit"
                           class="btn btn-lg bg-gradient-primary btn-lg w-100 mt-4 mb-0"
                            value="Save">
                </div>

            </div>
        </form>
```

The question linked highlights the differences between onLoad and document read but it does not answer the question of why a jquery function does not work

Comment: You're using window.load, but not the equivalent doc.ready - so it's possible that `$("#edit-assignment")` returns no elements at the time the code runs - it's unclear if your script is in the head or at the end of the body.   In the first case, wrap your event in a doc.ready:  `$(function() { $("#edit-assignment")... });`

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Feel free to respond as an answer and I will mark correct